# laravel eloquent use `whereHas` and `orWhereHas` with Fixed where

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query:

```
$undeliveredTransactions = Transaction::whereHas('carts.acceptedcarts', function ($query) {
        $query->where('delivered', false);
    })->orWhereHas('carts' , function ($query){
        $query->where('full_accepted' , false);
    })->where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
```

The `where('user_id' , Auth::id())` is fixed and necessary, but two `whereHas` one of them is necessary.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, using an [Eloquent subquery](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#subquery-where-clauses)

```
$undeliveredTransactions = 
    Transaction::where('user_id', Auth::id()
        ->where(function ($q) {
            $q->whereHas('carts.acceptedcarts', function ($query) {
                $query->where('delivered', false);
            })->orWhereHas('carts' , function ($query){
                $query->where('full_accepted' , false);
            });
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `whereRelation`, so your query is:

```
$undeliveredTransactions = Transaction::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->whereRelation('carts.acceptedcarts', 'delivered', false)
->orWhereRelation('carts' , 'full_accepted' , false)->get();
```